# Soap WSDL with Null

Tags: c#, xml, null, wsdl, xml-nil

I need to specify a parameter in a function which is nullable.
This doesn't work:

```
<message name="SaveRequest">
    <part name="serialNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<serialNumber xsi:nil="true" />
```

See [w3.org XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref20)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and fixing my gramar:) 
But when I use:

  <message name="SaveSensorboxRequest"> 
    <serialNumber xsi:nil="true" xsd:type="int" />
  </message>

it dont work and i get error

WSDLException (at /definitions/message[3]/serialNumber): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Encountered unexpected 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/:serialNumber'.

where is problem? thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you declare the xsi namespace to http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance?  If so could you paste your full wsdl or relevant parts so we can see what the real problem is?